# How to avoid this weird status bar in the navigation view?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I tried to set `fitSystemWindow` to `true` or to `flase` for both, `coordinator layout` and the `navigation view`, but it still there..

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uj7W.jpg)

EDITED: Here the code, that weird `status bar` appears in top of the `navigation view`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mainPage"
        layout="@layout/main_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you plz show some code or post a clear picture

Comment: Post a code sample showcasing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Question Edited

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the other codes, but there is a similar demo and it works ok.The link is [here](https://github.com/jessiezh0320/DrawerLayoutDemo). 
You can refer to it.

The main code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#33B86C"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```